# Show/hide element based on clicked href of link

Tags: javascript, html, css

I am new to JavaScript and actually quite desperate by now

I have an HTML file that:

1. gets data from an XML file and displays them in various divs (e.g.  )
2. these divs are hidden (by default) by a class name (class='box')
3. when a link is clicked, I pass the 'href' to the function showContent, remove the #, and then look for an element with that ID in the document.
4. then I add a new class name ('show') - so that this element shows up!

If you run the code you will see that every time you click on a link a new div is displayed...

So current problems:

1. replace already shown divs with the new clicked ID so that only one div shows up every time.
2. How can I avoid inserting the onClick event in every single  tag - and make this more automated?

---

My code is as follows:

```
function showContent(obj)
{
var linkTo = obj.getAttribute("href");
var newlinkTo=linkTo.replace('#','');
//alert (newlinkTo);

document.getElementById(newlinkTo).innerHTML=" This is where the xml variable content should go";   
document.getElementById(newlinkTo).className += " Show";

return true;
}

<a href="#b0" onClick="return showContent(this);">
<div id="text_content"> link2 </div>
</a>

<a href="#b1" onClick="return showContent(this);">
<div id="text_content"> link 1 </div>
</a>

<div class='box' id='b0'> abstract content </div>
<div class='box' id='b1'> introduction content </div>
```

Comment: Might not be of interest, but JQuery is a relatively simple way of achieving these things.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This sort of thing is not hard to do without jQuery.

I would recommend using a hash-bang (#!) for Javascript activated links to keep it separate from other possible links with hashes. (script is at the bottom)

```
<div id="nav-links">

    <a href="#!b0">
    <div id="text_content"> link2 </div>
    </a>

    <a href="#!b1">
    <div id="text_content"> link 1 </div>
    </a>

</div>

<div class='box' id='b0'> abstract content </div>
<div class='box' id='b1'> introduction content </div>

<script type="text/javascript">

    var links = document.getElementById('nav-links').getElementsByTagName('a');
    for(var i = 0, link; link = links[i]; i++) {
        link.onclick = showContent;
        // Hide content divs by default
        getContentDiv(link).style.display = 'none';
    }
    // Show the first content div
    if(links.length > 0) showContent.apply(links[0]);

    var current;

    function showContent() {

        // hide old content
        if(current) current.style.display = 'none';

        current = getContentDiv(this);
        if(!current) return true;

        //current.innerHTML = "This is where the xml variable content should go";
        current.style.display = 'block';

        return true;

    }

    function getContentDiv(link) {

        var linkTo = link.getAttribute('href');

        // Make sure the link is meant to go to a div
        if(linkTo.substring(0, 2) != '#!') return;
        linkTo = linkTo.substring(2);

        return document.getElementById(linkTo);

    }

</script>​
```

Comment: Hi wnwall,
sorry could not get your script to work. The for loop doesn't invoke anything when any of the links are clicked. I even tried it with a simple alert and doesn't work...

Comment: However the //hide old content bit works...
I do not understand how (?) though...
can you please explain the meaning of the if (current) ... statement ??
Is this some kind of shortcut for the IF statement?
I don't get how it understands what to show/hide since this is the same variable: current=ocument.getElementById(linkTo)...

Comment: me again...
ok I think I got it...
current.style.display = 'none' will not work the first time since it has no value in it. But it will work from the 2nd time onwards...

Comment: Sorry about that. I have updated my code to work as intended. Here is a JSFiddle demonstration: http://jsfiddle.net/cFHA9/1/

Comment: And yes, you are correct. the `if(current)` line just checks to see if there is any value stored in the `current` variable.

Comment: Hello again,
sorry to bore you but the "for" loop still does not work.
Have you tried to paste the above code in an html file and see how it behaves?
also I need to return false, in the getContent function so that the default link action does not take place. It makes the page scroll down to the location of the anchor and I dont want that...
Thanks,
K.

Comment: Hmm... strange...
i  pasted the script inside <head></head> + it didn't work.
It works if it appears after the divs...

Comment: Yes, that's because the divs can't be retrieved from the document if they don't exist in the document yet. Javascript is executed wherever it is placed in the document. If you place it before the divs, the script will execute before the browser adds the divs to the document. If you want to place it in the head you will need to use some kind of "onready" method, and for a good one of those, you'll have to use a library or settle for `window.onload`.

Answer (score 2):

I'm not usually into using jQuery everywhere, but with it you could just do:

```
<a class='showContent' data='b0'/>
```

Your js:

```
var selected;

$('a.showContent').on('click',function(e){
     var toShow = $(this).attr('data');
     if(selected!==undefined) selected.removeClass('Show');
     selected = $(div+'#'+toShow);
     selected.addClass('Show');
 });
```

Not sure if this is what you want, but thought I'd suggest it.

Answer (score 2):

There is a WAY cleaner way to do this:

This is just my quick example, it can get EVEN cleaner than this, but this works for your case:

HTML:

```
<a href="#b0" id="b0-link" class="link" rel="b0">link b0</a>

<a href="#b1" id="b1-link" class="link" rel="b1">link b1</a>

<div class='box' id='b0'> abstract content </div>
<div class='box' id='b1'> introduction content </div>​​​​​​​​​
```

CSS:

```
#b0 { display: none; }

#b1 { display: none; }

a, div.text_content { display: inline; padding: 0 10px; }
```

JQUERY:

```
​$('.link').click(function(){
    var id = $(this).attr("rel");

    $('#'+id).slideToggle('slow');                      
});
```

​
Each link would have to have a REL attribute that is the same as the ID of the div element that you are trying to show.

Here is a JSFiddle to this example in action:

http://jsfiddle.net/CUJSM/5/

Comment: Thanks Mike,but unfortunately I have many links that is why i was looking for an automated way that wnwall provided below.

Comment: Let me play around with it. I know there is a way to do this using only one function. I have done it before, it's just not on the top of my head.

Comment: I changed my answer, this is probably more of what you are looking for. This sets each link with a REL attribute that matches the ID of the element you are showing and hiding. It then grabs that REL string and places it in the slideToggle function dynamically, therefore creating a dynamic function. You would only need to include this once. Again, the REL on the link has to match the ID of the element you are showing. Some markup is going to need changes, that's just the gist of it.